# include div structure of one php page in another

Tags: php, html

Here I'm trying to build a PHP page with dynamic mapping of divs from various files, so I used two PHP pages one is in the below try, I just wanted, that div structure under pre-header.php should sit inside `index.php` where I mentioned to include:

```
**index.php**

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
             <?php include("pre-header.php"); ?>
        </body>
    </html>

**pre-header.php**

    <?php 

    echo "<div class='header'></div>";

    ?>
```

The above try wasn't working, I just want the output like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
         <div class='header'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How to achieve?

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me! Do you get any errors or what is the result? (For error reporting copy this:  `<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 ?>`)

Comment: Have you checked if your include-path is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
         <?php include("pre-header.php"); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

pre-header.php

```
<?php
    echo '<div class="header"></div>';
?>
```

Both files should be in same directory.

Comment: What's the difference with the original?

Comment: Whats the difference between your code and OP's? Is this like a kids game: Find 9 Differences?

Comment: There is not great difference. I just recode and post it.

Comment: Then is this no answer! When it's the same code and it's not working for OP

Comment: @onetrickpony This fundamentally changes the answer. You should roll it back and post an answer yourself if you think it's the solution.

Comment: I don't think so, it's what the original poster meant to say. It just needed some clarification

Comment: @onetrickpony for sure it changes the answer! Because the original answer was just a copy&paste of code from the question! You added stuff and changed content!

Comment: OP's answer is "Both files should be in same directory". I only modified his code to ensure that's the case

Comment: @Rajohn Works the code how onetrickpony posted or works the original answer? onesrickpony Thats what i mean you modified the code! Similar or equals to i fixed his code!

Comment: @Rizier123 i just removed the php part which enclosed the div structure in pre-header.php , its worked

Comment: @Rajohn What? you removed the php tags in the pre-header file and it worked? Your sure you didn't get this output: `echo "
";`? If you didn't get this output thats weird!

Comment: @Rajohn So you are basically saying that your original code worked :-)

Comment: @jeroen , nope, i said in my original code i just lifted that php part.

Comment: in my question i asked the basic part of how to build a html page  dynamically by including the divs from one file to another... its clear now